# Find all strings which match the pattern

Tags: linux

Is there any command support to find the "exact" string(s) in the given input?

For example:

```
pattern='s.'
sample_input='abcdsasd kmsa so
msd ks'
some_command $sample_input $pattern
```

I wish it output:

```
sa
sd
sa
so
sd
```

I find a duplicated question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259747/print-all-matches-of-a-regular-expression-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `grep` has the `-o` (or `--only-matching`) switch and your shell supports here strings:

```
grep -o -- "$pattern" <<<"$sample_input"
```

Answer (score 0):

we prepare another var p which holds the escaped version of pat variable.

```
pat='s.'
p=${pat//\//\\/}
sample_input='abcdsasd kmsa so
msd ks'
```

Using `perl` in slurp mode so that the whole sample input is in one record `$_`

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$sample_input" | pat="$pat" \
perl -ln -0777e 'print for s/\n\z//r =~ /$ENV{pat}/sg'
```

Here we make use of `sed` in a pseudo code:

```
_DO_=':a'    _UNTIL_NOPAT_=${_DO_/:/t }
_SAVE_='h'   _RETRIEVE_='g'
_RM_PAT_='s/'"$p"'\(.*\)/\1/'
_SLURP_='$!{N;s/^/\n/;D;}'
_CHOMP_R='s/\('"$p"'\).*/\1/'
_CHOMP_L_n_PRNT='s/.*\('"$p"'\)/\1/p'

printf '%s\n' "$sample_input" |
sed -ne "
  ${_SLURP_}
  ${_DO_}
      ${_SAVE_}
          ${_CHOMP_R}
          ${_CHOMP_L_n_PRNT}
      ${_RETRIEVE_}
      ${_RM_PAT_}
  ${_UNTIL_NOPAT_}
"
```

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`, to find all the strings that match a shell pattern, you can use this approach:

```
pattern='s?' # equivalent of regexp 's.'
sample_input='abcdsasd kmsa so
msd ks'

set -o extendedglob
matches=()
: ${sample_input//(#m)$~pattern/${matches[1+$#matches]::=$MATCH}}
```

Which here gives:

```
$ print -r -- $matches
sa sd sa so sd
```

That has several advantages over an approach using GNU `grep -o`:

- it works whatever bytes or characters `$sample_input` may contain. In particular NUL and NL and bytes not forming part of valid characters (which would still be matched by `?` or `*`).
- it doesn't have to rely on a GNUism
- zsh patterns are significantly more expressive than standard regular expressions.

There are a few PCRE operators that don't have an equivalent in zsh wildcards (such as look around ones). If you wanted to use those, you could use zsh's builtin `pcre_match` command. The manual (see `info zsh pcre_match`) has an example  that does just that: extract matches into an array.